# Calculating the average lag between timestamps in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

My data has roughly the following structure:

```
client_id | visit_number | session_start_time | hit_count
```

I am currently using:

```
SELECT client_id, visit_number, SUM(hit_count) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY visit_number), 
session_start_time - LAG(session_start_time) OVER (PARTITION by client_id ORDER BY visit_number)
FROM session_table
```

Ideally, I would like to have the rolling sum of a client's hits (this seems to be working correctly). It would also be convenient to have the average delta between successive sessions. Hopefully, my approach to calculating just one delta for the current session is correct, but I am not sure about a reasonable way to calculate the average delta.

One idea is to wrap the query above into a CTE and then calculate the average in another window function, but I believe it can be done in one query.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do you mean by "average delta between successive sessions"?  There is only one delta as you have defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the average time between sessions up to this session, then you can calculate it by taking the current time and subtracting the first time and dividing by one less than the number of sessions:

```
SELECT client_id, visit_number,
       SUM(hit_count) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY visit_number), 
       session_start_time - LAG(session_start_time) OVER (PARTITION by client_id ORDER BY visit_number) as delta,
       (session_start_time - 
        MIN(session_start_time) OVER (PARTITION by client_id)
       ) / NULLIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY session_start_time) - 1, 0) as avg_delta       
FROM session_table;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to achieve.. May I ask you an even simpler question? Using `ORDER BY` inside `OVER()` for `MIN` and `MAX` is not incorrect, but doesn't change the result because the ordering doesn't matter in this case within the partition. It's different with `SUM()` because we are interested in the running total and it's important to specify the partition ordering. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause in the partitioning syntax does a "cumulative" function.  This applies to `MIN()`, `MAX()`, and `SUM()`.  It affects all of them.  However, if the first value is the `MIN()`, then it will return the same results with or without the `ORDER BY`.